# Hints to speed up my canvas app

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, zooming

This is about WEB development, Canvas, HTML5.

I'm developping a paint application with HTML5 Canvas and JQuery. You can draw several layers, and you got a dynamic zoom with a magnifying glass effect.

The architecture is multiple canvas :

background :

- canvas-bg

layers :

- layer0
- layer1
- layer2

...

- layerN

tools :

- ghost (to display a "ghost" line when the user want to draw a line. Releasing mouse confirm the draw)
- magnify-layer

My problem is the zoom. To get the effect I want I redraw ALL LAYERS on the magnify-layer. Of course, when you are drawing a 2000*2000 picture, it is VERY slow. Moreoften, you can move the magnify-glass to zoom everywhere, and the redraw is recall on MouseMoveEvent.

To get it faster I only draw the little area under the glass (instead of entire layer). But it's still slow. How can I speed up know ?

illustration : http://imgur.com/hAtYsZi

You can see in the black circle the area is zoomed.
I used this code to start :

Démo : http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/167/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...it might help.

I'm guessing you're doing traditional "magnifying": you're displaying at reduced resolution and then "magnifying" at full resolution.

So, when the user selects the magnifier tool, "flatten" all your layers onto another canvas.

Then cache the flat canvas to an image at 1/2 resolution.  This becomes your unmagnified background.

Finally do your magnifying trick: Grabbing the appropriate pixels from the flattened canvas and show them in a floating magnifier.

Yes, there is some overhead+time in flattening your image, but that might be offset by the time it takes the user to select and position the magnifier.